# Mongoose find many and update all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and have a requirement to update many documents based on some calculations.

This is easy if I am querying one by one, but if I have say 50 items, I don't want to query and update one by one

What I am doing is curating a query to pull back multiple documents so I can loop through them all and make changes.

However, you can't call save on multiple objects, like you can with findOne. Its my first time with Mongoose, but in Entity Framework, I can edit the returned results from a query and call saveChanges() to update every item that has changed

I want to do something like this

```
item.find(query).exec(function(err, items) {
  for (i in items) {
     // change stuff
  }
  items.save(function (err) {
    // saved
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If u r using Promise library u can do like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var saveQuery=[];
item.find(query).exec(function(err, items) {
  for (i in items) {
     // change stuff
  }
saveQuery.push(item.save()); // Write your save query
}
    return Promise.all(saveQuery); // this will do your all save queries at once simultaneously.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do some simple changes to these docs, maybe

`update({_id:{$in:[a,b,c]}}, {$inc:{score:1}}, {multi:true}).exec()`  could help.